# nativescript-google-maps-sdk use native calls to style the map

Tags: google-maps, nativescript

I successfully integrated a google map at my angular2+nativescript project. Everything I needed from the typescript definition file is working for me.

However, I wanted to play around with the styling of the map.  AFAIK, I have to use native calls to the map, as the method setMapStyle() is not in the typescript definition.

I thought I could use the gMap property to access the native object and call the method. But I fail in setting up the right parameter as requested in google docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) as I dont know how to create a MapStyleOptions object. The type is unknown.

Anyone tried or succeeded in this task yet and want to share some hints? How would you access native GoogleMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript allows you to access all public API of plugins used in the app, therefore you should be able to make native calls to the Map API as per the documentation at [nativescript.org](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript)

If you want to create a MapStyleOptions object for example, you'd write

```
var MapStyleOptions : any = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
var mapStyle : any = new MapStyleOptions({"..":".."});
```

or just `var mapStyle = new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions({"..":".."});`

When TypeScript complains about `com.google...` not being recognized, you can either define it as `any` or import some ready to use typings.
Good luck!